# Email Alert in flow doesn't show bounced errors

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert, deliverability

I'm developing a flow to send Email Alert, but when I test this flow using an unavailable email like "*@test.com" I don't receive an error message of hard bounced. The only error I can track in this flow is when I try to send an email to a Case that doesn't have a Contact. Is there a way to track bounced errors in a flow?

My flow:

[image]

The message from debug:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the flow, there isn't a way to capture a bounced email. The issue is that an email doesn't get bounced until, technically, after the email has been *sent* by the flow element successfully.

A [Fault Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide/vpm_designer_elements_connector_fault.htm) will only catch errors in sending the email.

> a fault connector is executed at runtime only when its source element
> results in an error.

If the email has all the relevant information (to address, etc), the source element (email alert) completes successfully. Your example of there being no contact is a scenario where it's not possible to even send the email and that's why the fault connector works.

Unfortunately, a hard or soft bounce are issues in *delivering* that email (ex. returned to sender).

Your best bet would be to leverage [Bounce Management](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=emailadmin_bounce_enable.htm&type=5) in Salesforce. You can even set it to `Return bounced emails to sender` for immediate feedback/realization the email didn't go through.

`Setup --> Deliverability --> Activate bounce management`

As the emails seem to be related to cases/contacts, this can help identify [Contacts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) with invalid email addresses as the following fields get auto-populated asynchronously by the system after bounced emails:

- Email Bounced Date
- Email Bounced Reason
- Is Email Bounced

You can [create reports](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000327320&type=1) on these fields to keep track of contacts getting flagged for bounced emails to take action on. Likewise, if `IsEmailBounced` is true (there's an `EmailBouncedReason`) on a given contact, end users will see the following error when attempting to send emails through the UI

[image]

Unfortunately, the above error doesn't occur on email alerts running against that Contact.